# Unmarshalling unknown type code

Tags: android, android-intent

What I am basically trying to do is pass a Parcelable object as an Intent extra.

Here is where I pass it,

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(_context,
                    AddReminderActivity.class);

            final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(AddReminderActivity.EXTRA_MODE, AddReminderActivity.MODE_EDIT);
            bundle.putParcelable(AddReminderActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER, _reminders.get(position));

            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            _context.startActivity(intent);
```

`_reminders` is an `ArrayList<Reminder>`

Here is my `Reminder` class

```
package au.com.elegantmedia.vetcheck.objects;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;


public class Reminder implements Parcelable {

    private long _id;
    private String _message = "n/a";
    private String _medication = "n/a";
    private String _dosage = "n/a";
    private String _date = "n/a";
    private String _time = "n/a";
    private int _repeatID = 0;  // 1-once, 2-hourly, 3-daily, 4-weekly, 5-monthly
    private String _repeat = "n/a";
    private int _requestCode = 0;

    private static int REPEAT_ID_ONCE = 1;
    private static String REPEAT_ONCE = "once";
    private static int REPEAT_ID_HOURLY = 2;
    private static String REPEAT_HOURLY = "hourly";
    private static int REPEAT_ID_DAILY = 3;
    private static String REPEAT_DAILY = "daily";
    private static int REPEAT_ID_WEEKLY = 4;
    private static String REPEAT_WEEKLY = "weekly";
    private static int REPEAT_ID_MONTHLY = 5;
    private static String REPEAT_MONTHLY = "monthly";

    public Reminder() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Reminder(Parcel source) {
        _id = source.readInt();
        _message = source.readString();
        _medication = source.readString();
        _dosage = source.readString();
        _date = source.readString();
        _time = source.readString();
        _repeatID = source.readInt();
        _repeat = source.readString();
        _requestCode = source.readInt();
    }

    public long getID() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setID(long id) {
        _id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return _message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        if(!message.equals("")) {
            _message = message;
        }
    }

    public String getMedication() {
        return _medication;
    }

    public void setMedication(String medication) {
        if(!medication.equals("")) {
            _medication = medication;
        }
    }

    public String getDosage() {
        return _dosage;
    }

    public void setDosage(String dosage) {
        if(!dosage.equals("")) {
            _dosage = dosage;
        }
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return _date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        if(!date.equals("")) {
            _date = date;
        }
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return _time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        if(!time.equals("")) {
            _time = time;
        }
    }

    public void setRepeatID(String repeat) {
        if(repeat.equals(REPEAT_ONCE)) {
            _repeatID = REPEAT_ID_ONCE;
        }
        else if(repeat.equals(REPEAT_HOURLY)) {
            _repeatID = REPEAT_ID_HOURLY;
        }
        else if(repeat.equals(REPEAT_DAILY)) {
            _repeatID = REPEAT_ID_DAILY;
        }
        else if(repeat.equals(REPEAT_WEEKLY)) {
            _repeatID = REPEAT_ID_WEEKLY;
        }
        else if(repeat.equals(REPEAT_MONTHLY)) {
            _repeatID = REPEAT_ID_MONTHLY;
        }
    }

    public int getRepeatID() { 
        return _repeatID;
    }

    public void setRepeat(int repeatID) {
        _repeatID = repeatID;

        if(repeatID == REPEAT_ID_ONCE) {
            _repeat = REPEAT_ONCE;
        }
        else if(repeatID == REPEAT_ID_HOURLY) {
            _repeat = REPEAT_HOURLY;
        }
        else if(repeatID == REPEAT_ID_DAILY) {
            _repeat = REPEAT_DAILY;
        }
        else if(repeatID == REPEAT_ID_WEEKLY) {
            _repeat = REPEAT_WEEKLY;
        }
        else if(repeatID == REPEAT_ID_MONTHLY) {
            _repeat = REPEAT_MONTHLY;
        }
    }

    public String getRepeat() {
        return _repeat;
    }

    public void setRequestCode(int requestID) {
        _requestCode = requestID;
    }

    public int getRequestCode() {
        return _requestCode;
    }

    // parceling part
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Reminder> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Reminder>() {

        @Override
        public Reminder createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Reminder(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Reminder[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Reminder[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(_id);
        dest.writeString(_message);
        dest.writeString(_medication);
        dest.writeString(_dosage);
        dest.writeString(_date);
        dest.writeString(_time);
        dest.writeInt(_repeatID);
        dest.writeInt(_requestCode);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when passing the bundle from the caller activity it is like this,

```
Bundle[{reminder=au.com.elegantmedia.vetcheck.objects.Reminder@41fade98, mode=edit}]
```

meaning everything is set as expected, but when trying to access the extras from the callee activity (`final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();`) it is as follows,

```
Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=308]
```

and at the point I try to access the bundle as follows,

```
if(bundle.getString(EXTRA_MODE).equals(MODE_ADD)) {

        }
        else if(bundle.getString(EXTRA_MODE).equals(MODE_EDIT)) {
            final Reminder reminder = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_REMINDER);
            populateData(reminder);
        }
```

I run into the following Exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime(17991): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@416ee8b0: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6357102 at offset 172
```

This is my first attempt on Parcelable objects so I have very little idea what this means and Googling for a couple of hours hasn't exactly helped to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your `_id` is of type `long` and you are unmarshalling it as type `int`:

```
    _id = source.readInt();
```

Shouldn't it be

```
    _id = source.readLong();
```

I also noticed that you are not reading in the same order as writing it to the parcel. `_repeat` is not written to the parcel while marshalling.

Comment: "I also noticed that you are not reading in the same order as writing it to the parcel. _repeat is not written to the parcel while marshalling." While it's bad practice on my part in the long/int case :) this was the actual problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am so emotionally affected by this answer and especially this one 
**"I also noticed that you are not reading in the same order as writing it to the parcel. _repeat is not written to the parcel while marshalling."**, ripped my brain